Carbureted Motorcycle Engine doesn't start when hot
As the title says, I'm working on a vintage motorcycle that cannot be started by cranking when the engine is hot - I'm able to start it however by rolling downhill (engage the clutch after getting some speed).
It's a longitudinal V2 750cc engine (Moto Guzzi) with round slide (non-CV) carbs (dell'orto PHBH).
The internet usually suspects vapor lock, but these are gravity-fed carburetors with bowls. They should be able to start the engine just with the fuel in the bowls.
Both cylinders have good compression when cold. One one head, I've replaced the valves due to an excessively worn valve guide (which was replaced as well, of course). Naturally, valve play has been adjusted on both cylinders.
The carbs have been cleaned ultrasonically, float height was brought to spec, and worn needle valves replaced. The intake rubber boots have been replaced as well.
The OEM ignition system (points) was replaced by a PO with an electronic aftermarket ignition system (magnetic pickup) - which so far performs satisfactorily.
Spark plugs have been gapped per spec, after a short test drive one of the plugs looks proper (slight light gray tinge, no soot, dry), the other slightly oily, pointing to probably worn piston rings (cold compression on this cylinder is very good though). While this is certainly less than ideal, I do not expect this to make the engine not starting at all (the "good" cylinder should at least fire).
The battery is (comparably) fresh, and cranks the engine alright - the cranking voltage drops to 9.66V initially, but recovers to 12V within 0.5secs and stays there during cranking. So this should be fine.
The engine runs very smooth, starts easily when cold, and does idle nicely and stable, without tumbling. It's rather confusing.
Addendum: The carbs have a manual choke; which I engage under cold start (but are not needed every time). Under hot conditions, I don't use it, of course - but even with choke when hot, the engine doesn't want to start by cranking.

Have you checked for a good spark while the engine is hot?

Not yet, as I assumed it to be fine since I'm able to start it by rolling downhill. I will do so and update the question.

I was able to track this down to an static ignition timing advance that has been set slightly too early. I assume that under hot conditions and the electrical circuit loaded down by the starter this resulted no spark, or too weak a spark to ignite a mixture that perhaps also was less than ideal. I retarded the static ignition timing by 1-2 degrees and am now able to start the engine as one would expect from a carburetted engine.

This line of reasoning is now moot with the newly added info about the manual choke, but I'm leaving it here for the benefit of others looking for a solution to the same problem.
Does the carb have an automatic choke?
With a manual choke, a carb needs some choke to start when cold, but if you use the same choke when hot, the engine won't start.
If this carb has an automatic choke, it's possible that the bimetallic (temperature sensitive) spring that prevents or minimizes choke when hot is not working correctly.
Can you take the air cleaner off and watch the carb during starting? When cold, you should see some choke and when hot, no choke or less choke.

No, these have manually operated chokes, which I only engage during cold starts. I'll update the question.

Perhaps the carb(s)s are contaminated from tank sediment not filtered out? Can you test for spark on a hot engine when the starter fails to fire up the engine?
